# Create pivot like control Windows Phone Silverlight in WinRT and bind Items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Hi I wanna recreate pivot control in Windows Phone and use it in my Windows Store apps (WinRT). I already tried this [MyToolkit](https://github.com/MyToolkit/Core) but it seems I can not find option to bind my collection. So I want my pivot header is a collection from my items and my pivot items is a collection from selected collection from pivot. My Collection is like this

```
//Class to bind in pivot
public class CategoryBooks
{
    public string CategoryName{get;set;}// This is for binding in my pivot header
    public List<Book> Books{get;set;}// This is for binding in my pivot item ListView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They built their Pivot on top of Control instead of ItemsControl as Microsoft's implementation.

I didn't try to run the samples but I don't understand their control logic. I'd recommend to retarget your app to win 10 if having a good pivot implementation is a strong need.

You could try the Hub control that has a close behavior (although the headers behave differently)